# Check if variable is_undefined in PHP

Tags: php, isset, isnull, isnullorempty

In PHP, I want to check if a variable has not been set/defined, **where setting a variable NULL is considered set/defined**.

I'm aware everything here:
http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php
including isset(), empty(), and is_null(). None of these appear to be what I'm looking for. Consider the following example:

```
<?php 
$myNull = null;
echo 'isset($myNull): "'.isset($myNull).'"<br />';
echo '$myNull value = "'.$myNull . '"<br />';

echo "<br />";

echo 'isset($myUndefined): "'.isset($myUndefined).'"<br />';
echo '$myUndefined value = "'.$myUndefined . '"<br />';
?>
```

This example outputs something like:
isset($myNull): ""
$myNull value = ""

isset($myUndefined): ""
Notice: **Undefined** variable: myUndefined in C:\wamp\www\plm\temp4.php on line 9
$myUndefined value = ""

I want to know if a variable is **Undefined** as it says above in the notice. I want a function, call it "is_undefined", where

```
$myNull = null;
is_undefined($myNull); // is false
is_undefined($myUndefined); // is true
```

Anyone? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I haven´t used it yet - but I think that "get_defined_vars" should be worth a look...
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

I would give it a try and dump the result.

Comment: Also, if you are within the global scope you can check if array_key_exists in $GLOBALS.

Comment: I was doubtful there was a solution out there. This works great though, thanks! I used it in conjunction with array_key_exists($key, $array).

Answer (score 10):

I think that [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) is a good candidate for such job:

```
array_key_exists('myNull', get_defined_vars());
```

Should do what you expect.

If you work on a global context, you can also use:

```
array_key_exists('myNull', $GLOBALS);
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want an is_undefined function I would prefer not to work with arrays so I would do this:

```
function is_undefined(&$test) {
    return isset($test) && !is_null($test);
}
```

So when you `echo isset($myNull);` it converts the boolean(true) to "". thats why the value is blank.  If you want to see it on the screen you can do `var_dump(isset($myNull));` that will display if it's true or false.

Also you have an echo of $myUndefined but it's not set yet so that's why you get a warning.  What you want to do is:

```
if (!empty($myUndefined)) {
    // variable is defined so do something with it
    echo '$myUndefined value = "' . $myUndefined . '"<br />';
} else {
    echo 'Oops, $myUndefined is Undefined!<br />";
}
```

Here is a brief overview of isset() vs. is_null() vs. empty()

```
$foo = null;
// isset($foo) == true;
// empty($foo) == true;
// is_null($foo) == true;

// Notice I don't set $foo2 to anything
// isset($foo2) == false;
// empty($foo2) == true;
// is_null($foo2) throws a notice!

$foo3 = false;
// isset($foo2) == true;
// empty($foo2) == true;
// is_null($foo2) == false;

$foo4 = 1234;
// isset($foo2) == true;
// empty($foo2) == false;
// is_null($foo2) == false;
```

Comment: `is_null()` will cause `E_NOTICE` if the variable is undefined.

Comment: `empty()` returns `true` if it is a defined `NULL` variable :)

Comment: I know this is OCD, but your closing quote in the second string should be a `'` not a `"`... the red semicolon and close bracket is driving me nuts, and I can't change it because it's a single character edit.

Comment: Haha @JasonNichols I edited my post about 30 seconds before you commented. I hate that too!

Comment: @GGio using `empty()` on a not set variable will NOT give you a notice. Trust me I checked ;)

Comment: @GGio my entire code: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); empty($test);` Result? No notices! So either you're understanding php.net incorrectly or there's a typo on their site. Trust me. Try it your self

Comment: @GGio... haha... oops? amiright? hehe delete your comments so you don't look silly :)

Comment: +1 Very nice solution where you can use the real variable instead of just the name as a string (the `get_defined_vars()` solutions...).

Comment: You missed the point @chrislondon, and you didn't read my post very well. I said I understand all those functions and none of them work. I said is_undefined() should return false if set NULL, and true if never set. A simple test would show your function returns false and false.

Comment: This `is_undefined` implementation is improperly returning `false` for variables set to `null` and yields the *exact* same results as `isset` for defined, undefined, and variables set to null. The `&& !is_null($test)` part is completely redundant.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`compact()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) for this too, if the variable you give it isn't in the symbol table it returns an empty array, otherwise an array containing the variable name/value pair, just cast the result to a boolean

```
<?php

$myNull = null;

$isDefined = (bool) compact('myNull'); // true

$otherIsDefined = (bool) compact('myUndefined'); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OOP then use overloading `__isset()` this function will execute when you are trying to access a variable that is not defined anywhere. example:

```
 public function __isset($name) {
    echo 'Hello';
 }
```

Thus, will avoid any error message or notice related to undefined variable

Comment: I like the idea, but take care because `property_exists` will not call your magic method: this can be confusing in some ways.

Comment: I am using OOP, but I want more than just to kill the notice, I want to check if a variable has been set ($asdf = "anything", or $asdf = null, or etc). This may still work in some way, but I prefer the get_defined_vars() functions. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just like Mr. Jonathan mentioned above, we could use array_key_exists() + $GLOBALS rather than get_defined_vars() to identify Undefined variable to null

```
$x;  // $x is undefined 
$y=null;  // $y is defined and is NULL type variable with the only null value
$z=[];    // $z is an array object

if( array_key_exists('x', $GLOBALS) && is_null($x) ) echo "\$x exists and is null\n";
if( array_key_exists('y', $GLOBALS) && is_null($y) ) echo "\$y exists and is null\n";
if( array_key_exists('z', $GLOBALS) && is_null($z) ) echo "\$he exists and is null\n";

// output 
$y exists and is null
```

Answer (score 0):

To check a variable is define and have some value we can use `isset()` in a condition

```
if(!isset($var)){}
```