# Differentiating between NULL and not defined in PHP

Tags: php, null, isset

is there any way to differentiate between a variable not having been defined yet or had been defined but is set to 'NULL'

Comment: Duplicate of *Check if variable is_undefined in PHP* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993027/check-if-variable-is-undefined-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if variable is\_undefined in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993027/check-if-variable-is-undefined-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

You can read about NULL [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php).

After a little more digging it may be possible to use [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/get_defined_vars) and check for the variable name as a key in the returned array.

This works even if the var was assigned NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can check $GLOBALS, if it contains certain key. Does not work for variables defined inside functions:

```
array_key_exists('variable name', $GLOBALS);
```

For objects, check *property_exists* function.

---

Although, I'd suggest that you avoid creating any code that relies on (in)existence of any variable. If you use a var, it should be defined from start of the script/object instantiation. If you have to carry more information, that you can hold in value/null, you should not go for value/null/unset way, you might want to create another boolean var, etc. And I recommend creating a code that won't issue any E_NOTICE because of operations on inexistent variables.

Comment: in my particular case property_exists saved the day ... but for normal operations get_defined_vars() as mentioned by @hades2510 seems more appropiate